# In IntelliJ IDEA, is the project itself also a module?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14

When I right-click the Project Name (effectively the Workspace in other IDE's), in the menu are a few references to it being a module ("`remove module ___`", "`make module ___`", "`compile module ___`", where `___` is the project name.

**QUESTION 1:** So is an IDEA project conceptually *also* a module, or have I configured this incorrectly?

To be clear, I've also noticed that the folder hierarchy for the project (named "WorkspaceI") looks like this (trailing \ indicates a folder):

```
F:\DEVEL\WorkspaceI\.idea\
F:\DEVEL\WorkspaceI\ALife\
F:\DEVEL\WorkspaceI\out\
F:\DEVEL\WorkspaceI\src\
F:\DEVEL\WorkspaceI\TGM_Common\
F:\DEVEL\WorkspaceI\WorkspaceI.iml
```

`ALife` and `TGM_Common` are modules.  I understand how `out\` was configured to hold all the module's class files.

**QUESTION 2:** But what is the `src` folder for?  Some sort of source hierarchy common to all modules?  That's what module dependencies are for.

Comment: AFAIK you can create a project and at the same time create a module for that project that has the same name of the project. If you don't want this, then you can create an empty project and then add the proper modules to it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, Ah....so you think I inadvertently created it as both a module and project?  Is that by default without creating the blank project you say?

Comment: src is where you put your source code files.

Comment: @JNYRanger, each module has its own `src` folder.  This is a cleaner implementation because it allows a module to duplicate a file (and hence override) one in a dependent module.  I'm able to experiment with code changes in an entirely different module.

Comment: @tgm1024 I know, i didn't realize you were referring only to the top src folder.  Now that I re-read your question it makes more sense: That one is for the module that gets created automatically if you didn't create an empty project.

Comment: It's not a *bad* policy per se, but it is a little off-putting when you're first evaluating the IDE....it's not an intuitive concept to me.  But then, I'm only comparing it to Eclipse, Netbeans, and (way long ago) Visual Cafe for Java.

Comment: To the person who pedantically edited my subject line to remove the explicit reference to "IntelliJ IDEA", please knock it off.  Just because there is a tag to IntelliJ IDEA in place, does not make it read clearly in the search results.  There is also a "java" tag, and someone might think inadvertently that I was referring to all java projects.  FURTHER, I might well add a tag in the future referencing the other IDEs that don't exhibit this behavior.  This kind of knee-jerk drive by editing has got to come to an end here at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a project is conceptually not a module. However, it's very common to have a module with the same root as the project root, in which case you will see module-related actions when you invoke the context menu on the root directory of your project. There is nothing incorrect about this configuration.

The "src" folder is the source root of your module which has the same root as the project root. It's not shared with any other modules; it's true that sharing code between modules is accomplished through module dependencies.